# django ORM problem - Annotate and aggregate return inconsistent values

Tags: django, django-orm, django-aggregation

**I found a setup where `aggregate()` and `annotate()` do NOT return the same values... I am really confused.**

I have the following models:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    pass

class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, related_name="items")
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=1)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=False, blank=False, default=0)
    begin = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

When I want to get the total revenue over a timespan, I have the following query:

```
revenue = Invoice.objects.annotate(
               first_date=Min('items__begin')).filter(
               first_date__range=[start_date, end_date]).aggregate(
               revenue=Sum(F('items__amount') * F('items__price'),               
                           output_field=FloatField()))['revenue']
```

I tried to do the same with `annotate()` just to verify the results:

```
revenue_list = Invoice.objects.annotate(
                  first_date=Min('items__begin')).filter(
                  first_date__range=[start_date, end_date]).annotate(
                  revenue=Sum(F('items__amount') * F('items__price'),               
                              output_field=FloatField()))
```

When I now loop over the elements and manually sum up `revenue` I get a different value than `revenue`.

Any ideas? Unfortunately after an aggregation you cannot check the raw query anymore...

Thanks!

PS: I checked the values manually with SQL. `annotate` is right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. `distinct()` or `values()` did not work but to move the multiplication to a second `annotate`:

```
revenue =  Invoice.objects.annotate(
               first_date=Min('items__begin')).filter(
               first_date__range=[start_date, end_date]).annotate(
               revenue_invoice=Sum(F('items__amount') * F('items__price'),
                                   output_field=FloatField())).aggregate(
               revenue=Sum('revenue_invoice', output_field=FloatField()))['revenue']
```